How to write test cases where the mocked objects are not giving anything back
How to write assert or verify for these. I cannot change the code in any way. Only Junit can be written by me.
public void Calculator(booker, product) {
  Matcher matcher = buildCriteria(product);
  matcher.setID(1);
  matcher.setTravel("Air");

  if (null != product) {
    populate(booker, product);
  }
}

only these are there. those methods that are called are private and doesnt change the state or behavior of the parameter objects in any way. So how can i verify or assert this? Also, i cannot use PowerMock.

This question is similar to: Mockito. Verify method arguments. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

What do you want to assert? If nothing changes, there's nothing to assert. What does populate do? Also note that your code does not compile (parameters are missing their types)
